# how to extract data in paragraph using regex

Tags: python, .net, regex, vb.net, c++11

Customer Reference N139211508474572 Entry Date 05/19/2021 Extra Information NEFT IN UTR FROM **S S DISTRIBUTOR** N139211508474 572TXN REF NO 23621001323

How can I extract the vender company name like S S DISTRIBUTOR, In this FROM is constant in multiple data I have, I did the regex code to extract customer reference number(?<=Customer Reference ).+(?= Entry Date) like this it's working, and give me a code to extract the vender company name.

The customer reference number is not constant it will have mixed numbers and alphabets or only numbers.

Comment: Regular expressions is a blunt force instrument used to bludgeon many problems into submission. It's not always the right (and almost never the simple) solution. Have you tried counting spaces to find the data you need?

Comment: Additionally, please update your tags. Which language are you using exactly? Can you also show your code and what you have tried?

Comment: I need this code for uipath, using this code I am extracting pdf data

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the vender company name is located between the keyword `FROM` and the customer reference number, would you please try:

```
Customer Reference (.*).* FROM (.*) \1
```

The Group2 captures the vendor company name `S S DISTRIBUTOR`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Y2pxY/1)

Comment: Thks for reply,

Comment: For using that code the out put is (Customer Reference N139211508474572 Entry Date 05/19/2021 Extra Information NEFT IN UTR FROM S). This is the output I got

Comment: As you are not specifying the language you use, I could provide the regex101 solution at best. Can you provide the code you test to reproduce the mentioned output?

Comment: I am extracting data using uipath RPA process, I don't know the language.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what language you were actually using, and as [@some-programmer-dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67831340/how-to-extract-data-in-paragraph-using-regex/67831486#comment119894822_67831340) mentioned regex is not necessarily the best solution for searching in a string.

You tagged `python` so assuming that is what you are using, you can consider using `split` and `index` to get whatever is after `FROM` and 2 words before `REF`:

```py
s = "Customer Reference N139211508474572 Entry Date 05/19/2021 Extra Information NEFT IN UTR FROM S S DISTRIBUTOR N139211508474 572TXN REF NO 23621001323"
# Convert all to UPPER case first
s = s.upper()
# Clean unnecessary whitespaces first just in case
s = " ".join(s.split())
# Get all text after FROM
s = s.split("FROM")[1]
# Get all text which are 2 words before REF
index_of_REF = s.split().index("REF")
s = " ".join(s.split()[:index_of_REF-2])
print(s)
```

This gives:

```
S S DISTRIBUTOR
```